# HTMLAgilityPack doesn't take url parameters into account

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I want to pull data from this url:

https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/index.php?sort=

Notice how it lists A-Z on the same page when `sort = ""` instead of a character.

Unfortunately the following code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(@"https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/index.php?sort=", "GET");
```

Has been using the url up to index.php. Everything after `?` is not taken into account.

I'm sure the answer is simple but googling has not helped me at all for some reason htmlagilitypack has no documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd try and use `WebRequest.Create()` to get closer to the code on this. You can see the source code for `HtmlWeb.Load` on [the CodePlex site](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/1_4_0/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlWeb.cs).

Comment: `HtmlWeb` list all A-Z just fine when I tried, see the demo here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/gtDjfv

Comment: @har07 Thanks. I have no clue why my code didn't work but I think I'll just use your code anyway. I was getting really strange output. Must have something to do streamwriter or something. I'll just use your code now